# Returning data from URLSession and saving in property variable

Tags: ios, swift, api, session

I try to get some data from server using ***URLSession.shared.dataTask***.
It works fine, but I can't save result like a class variable. 
Many answers recommend to use ***completion Handler***, but it doesn't help for my task.

Here is my testing code:

```
class PostForData {
func forData(completion:  @escaping (String) -> ()) {
    if let url = URL(string: "http://odnakrov.info/MyWebService/api/test.php") {
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let postString : String = "json={\"Ivan Bolgov\":\"050-062-0769\"}"
        print(postString)
        request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) {
            data, response, error in
            let json = String(data: data!, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
                completion(json)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
}
class ViewController: UIViewController {
var str:String?
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let pfd = PostForData()

    pfd.forData { jsonString in
        print(jsonString)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.str = jsonString
        }
    }
    print(str ?? "not init yet")
}
}
```

Comment: Your print function will execute before the network operation is complete. You can only access `self.str` in the completion handler or after the completion handler has run

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you for help. Could you explain how to use 'self.str' after completion handler will stop work?

Comment: You really need to do whatever it is you want to do with the string in the completion handler. You can use a dispatch group and display your group notify to execute another closure when the task is done.

Comment: @Paulw11 It is really want I need. I will try to use DispatchGroup. But if I need to use this string response all around in my app, I need to write bigger part of code in closures. Is it OK?

Comment: FWIW, I would not recommend `DispatchGroup`. As documentation says: "`DispatchGroup` allows for aggregate synchronization of work. You can use them to submit multiple different work items and track when they all complete, even though they might run on different queues. This behavior can be helpful when progress can’t be made until all of the specified tasks are complete." That's not the situation here. At best, it's overkill.

Comment: Normally you would call a function from the closure that does what you need. That way you keep the code that is directly in the closure manageable

Comment: @Rob I try **'DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.label.text = self.str
        }'** But it doesnt load value.

Comment: Also, a dispatch group is just going to substitute one closure for another. I mentioned it as a technique you could use, but I agree in this situation it doesn't make sense

Comment: That is dispatching the code onto the main queue, which is required if you are updating UI elements, but it won't change the order of execution; the code inside the closure is going to execute asynchronously after the code following the closure

Comment: Thank you a lot. Can I vote up for your answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This closure is `@escaping` (i.e. it's asynchronously called later), so you have to put it inside the closure:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

    var str: String?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let pfd = PostForData()

        pfd.performRequest { jsonString, error in
            guard let jsonString = jsonString, error == nil else {
                print(error ?? "Unknown error")
                return
            }

            // use jsonString inside this closure ...

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.str = jsonString
                self.label.text = jsonString
            }
        }

        // ... but not after it, because the above runs asynchronously (i.e. later)
    }
}
```

Note, I changed your closure to return `String?` and `Error?` so that the the view controller can know whether an error occurred or not (and if it cares, it can see what sort of error happened).

Note, I renamed your `forData` to be `performRequest`. Generally you'd use even more meaningful names than that, but method names (in Swift 3 and later) should generally contain a verb that indicates what's being done.

```
class PostForData {
    func performRequest(completion:  @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
        // don't try to build JSON manually; use `JSONSerialization` or `JSONEncoder` to build it

        let dictionary = [
            "name": "Ivan Bolgov",
            "ss": "050-062-0769"
        ]
        let jsonData = try! JSONEncoder().encode(dictionary)

        // It's a bit weird to incorporate JSON in `x-www-form-urlencoded` request, but OK, I'll do that.

        // But make sure to percent escape it.

        let jsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8)!
            .addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryValueAllowed)!

        let body = "json=" + jsonString
        let url = URL(string: "http://odnakrov.info/MyWebService/api/test.php")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = body.data(using: .utf8)

        // It's not required, but it's good practice to set `Content-Type` (to specify what you're sending)
        // and `Accept` (to specify what you're expecting) headers.

        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        // now perform the prepared request

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            completion(responseString, nil)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

There are also some modifications to that routine, specifically:

1. Don't ever use `!` forced unwrapping when processing server responses. You have no control over whether the request succeeds or fails, and the forced unwrapping operator will crash your app. You should gracefully unwrap these optionals with `guard let` or `if let` patterns.
2. It's exceedingly unusual to use `json=...` pattern where the `...` is the JSON string. One can infer from that you're preparing a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, and using `$_POST` or `$_REQUEST` to get the value associated with the `json` key. Usually you'd either do true JSON request, or you'd do `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request, but not both. But to do both in one request is doubling the amount of work in both the client and server code. The above code follows the pattern in your original code snippet, but I'd suggest using one or the other, but not both.
3. Personally, I wouldn't have `performRequest` return the JSON string. I'd suggest that it actually perform the parsing of the JSON. But, again, I left this as it was in your code snippet.
4. I notice that you used JSON in the form of `"Ivan Bolgov": "050-062-0769"`. I would recommend not using "values" as the key of a JSON. The keys should be constants that are defined in advantage. So, for example, above I used `"name": "Ivan Bolgov"` and `"ss": "050-062-0769"`, where the server knows to look for keys called `name` and `ss`. Do whatever you want here, but your original JSON request seems to conflate keys (which are generally known in advance) and values (what values are associated with those keys).
5. If you're going to do `x-www-form-urlencoded` request, you must percent encode the value supplied, like I have above. Notably, characters like the space characters, are not allowed in these sorts of requests, so you have to percent encode them. Needless to say, if you did a proper JSON request, none of this silliness would be required.

   But note that, when percent encoding, don't be tempted to use the default `.urlQueryAllowed` character set as it will allow certain characters to pass unescaped. So I define a `.urlQueryValueAllowed`, which removes certain characters from the `.urlQueryAllowed` character set (adapted from a pattern employed in Alamofire):

   ```
   extension CharacterSet {

       /// Returns the character set for characters allowed in the individual parameters within a query URL component.
       ///
       /// The query component of a URL is the component immediately following a question mark (?).
       /// For example, in the URL `http://www.example.com/index.php?key1=value1#jumpLink`, the query
       /// component is `key1=value1`. The individual parameters of that query would be the key `key1`
       /// and its associated value `value1`.
       ///
       /// According to RFC 3986, the set of unreserved characters includes
       ///
       /// `ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"`
       ///
       /// In section 3.4 of the RFC, it further recommends adding `/` and `?` to the list of unescaped characters
       /// for the sake of compatibility with some erroneous implementations, so this routine also allows those
       /// to pass unescaped.

       static var urlQueryValueAllowed: CharacterSet = {
           let generalDelimitersToEncode = ":#[]@"    // does not include "?" or "/" due to RFC 3986 - Section 3.4
           let subDelimitersToEncode = "!$&'()*+,;="

           var allowed = CharacterSet.urlQueryAllowed
           allowed.remove(charactersIn: generalDelimitersToEncode + subDelimitersToEncode)
           return allowed
       }()

   }
   ```

---

I would suggest changing your PHP to accept a JSON request, e.g.:

```
<?php

    // read the raw post data

    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $raw_post_data = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 8192);
    }
    fclose($handle);

    // decode the JSON into an associative array

    $request = json_decode($raw_post_data, true);

    // you can now access the associative array how ever you want

    if ($request['foo'] == 'bar') {
        $response['success'] = true;
        $response['value']   = 'baz';
    } else {
        $response['success'] = false;
    }

    // I don't know what else you might want to do with `$request`, so I'll just throw
    // the whole request as a value in my response with the key of `request`:

    $raw_response = json_encode($response);

    // specify headers

    header("Content-Type: application/json");
    header("Content-Length: " . strlen($raw_response));

    // output response

    echo $raw_response;
?>
```

Then you can simplify the building of the request, eliminating the need for all of that percent-encoding that we have to do with `x-www-form-urlencoded` requests:

```
class PostForData {
    func performRequest(completion:  @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void) {
        // Build the json body

        let dictionary = [
            "name": "Ivan Bolgov",
            "ss": "050-062-0769"
        ]
        let data = try! JSONEncoder().encode(dictionary)

        // build the request

        let url = URL(string: "http://odnakrov.info/MyWebService/api/test.php")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = data

        // It's not required, but it's good practice to set `Content-Type` (to specify what you're sending)
        // and `Accept` (to specify what you're expecting) headers.

        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")

        // now perform the prepared request

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                completion(nil, error)
                return
            }
            let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
            completion(responseString, nil)
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very useful for me! Thank you very much.

Comment: And I can't understand how to use JSON Request via PHP without $_POST array. I try to find some examples, but all use $_POST.

Comment: Updated question with example of how to write PHP that processes JSON request and how you can simplify `performRequest` to prepare JSON request.